# How can two processes in Android use same SQLite Database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-service

How can two processes in an Application, one an Activity and another a Service can use a common SQLite Database? This is not a question targeting very specific problem, but I looking for a solution from last three but no help.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Sure, write a DAO for your database and use the DAO in the service and in the Activity, and that's all

Comment: @DGomez I will need more specific help. Your comment is very broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a ContentProvider which will do all the work with SQLite and both applications will use it to access DB.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Content provider would probably be an overkill in this case, because he said he would access it from two activities, not applications.

Comment: actually,not activities, but still two processes. If it would be two apps, ContentProvider is a convenient solution

Comment: I agree. But not in this case I think. In the link I mention in my answer, there's nice comparison of ContentProvider vs singleton.

Comment: Neither two activities nor two application, these are two processes in one Application.

Comment: I suppose that SQLite DB belongs to an application, in this case you can freely use ContentProvider or instance of your class providing DB access for each process